# How to get data by query ref object in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I have an issue and failed to find what i am exactly looking for.
i have this `Ads` schema with references of others too:

```
    link: {
        type: String,
        default: 'n/a',
    },
    page: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'AdsPage',
        required: true,
    },
    slot: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'AdsSlot',
        required: true,
    },
```

and i want to get data by applying condition on `page` property, `page` is a schema which has url property in it.
page schema:

```
    {
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add page title'],
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        maxlength: [50, 'Name cannot be more then 50 characters'],
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Add page URL'],
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
},
```

i want to get all ads that matches provided page url.

my query looks like:

```
if (req.params.pageUrl) {
    const ads = await Ads.find({
        'page.url': req.params.pageUrl,
    });

    return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'Successfully fetched ads for specific page',
        count: ads.length,
        data: ads,
    });
}
```

page url in param is good, but somehow this filter is not working, i got no error but with zero results.
i have tried `$match` property but got some upper level error.

any help on query on nested ref object is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `aggregate` and `$lookup` to do it. You could see more detail in [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

Your `ads_pages` in output is your `adspages`. First element in aggregate array, `$lookup` will help you find the all matched condition which `_id` in adspage equal `page`in ads and `url` in `adspage` equal to your `req.params.pageUrl`.

Second element in aggregate array, `$match` will help you remove document contains empty ads_pages which means its condition doesn't match above conditions. You could use this https://jsfiddle.net/cuxvd2pm to test.

```js
await AdsModel.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            // This name must be same as your collection name "in the mongodb"
            // In my case, I must use lowercase string, and add more extra "s" in the end
            // If you didn't modify extra configuration, I think you should also do it.
            from: "adspages",

            // you could use as: "page" to replace the original field
            as: "ads_pages",
            let: { "page_id": "$page"},
            pipeline: [{ 
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $and: [
                            {$eq: ["$url", req.params.pageUrl]},
                            {$eq: ["$_id", "$$page_id"]}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            // when you change your `as field` to page
            // you should also change `ads_pages.0` to `page.0`
            "ads_pages.0": {
                $exists: true
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this doesn't seems to work.
May Ads Schema name is `Ads` and Ads page schema is `AdsPage`. 
may be i am confusing with names you have used.

https://jsfiddle.net/rdo7ukb5/

Comment: your `let: { page: '$page' }` is not the same as mine,  You should use `let: { "page_id": "$page"}` . Then, you just change the schema name `from: {your_schema_name}` which is from `mongoose.model('{here}', AdsPageScheme);`

Comment: i appreciate your help. but there are still no results and no error either

Comment: @ArslanAmeer You could use this example code to figure out how to use aggregate https://jsfiddle.net/cuxvd2pm. Make sure you replace the connection url with yours and run it with your environment.

Comment: Thank you jack. Your comment made it clear, yes i was using schema name instead of collection name, which is always plural and small case.
one more thing, can i replace existing `page` property with new `ads_page` property so i can have only one `page` property with page data in it ?

Comment: Use `as: "page"` and `$match: {"page.0": {$exists: true}}`.